# removeProp clearing MySQL INSERT

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm building a GCSE Selection website for the school I work for, but I'm encountering an issue.

I have 6 selection boxes, each with 16 options.

Once the 6 boxes have been selected, the client clicks submit and the information is then submit to our MySQL Database to be reviewed at a later date.

This is done in my php file:

```
/* Attempt MySQL server connection.*/
$link = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

// Check connection 
if($link === false){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO xxxxxx (username, dob, form, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, optRes1, optRes2) VALUES ('$username', '$dob', '$form', '$opt1', '$opt2', '$opt3', '$opt4', '$optRes1', '$optRes2')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

It has to work in such a way that when the client selects an option in a box, that option is then disabled in the other 5 boxes so the user cannot select the same option more than once. To achieve this I've used the following code in my index.html file:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">

$(function()
 {
  $('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'opt1' && $(this).val() == 'Default'){
        $('select').not(this).prop('disabled', true).val('Disabled');
    } else {
        $('select').not(this).removeProp('disabled');

        $('select option').removeProp('disabled');
        $('select').each(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val != 'Default' || val != 'Disabled'){
                $('select option[value="'+val+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
               }
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

The issue I'm facing is when the code above is in the index.html file, and the client clicks submit, the MySQL database only receives the $username and $dob data. The $form, $opt1, $opt2, $opt3, $opt4, $optRes1, $optRes2 are not received and those columns are not populated.

If I take the javascript out, it works fine.

Could anyone give me some pointers.

Thanks a lot,

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`$('select').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
 $('select option').prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: I've replaced my script with that, but after the functionality is lost and the user is able to select the same option multiple times. Was it only part of the code which needed changing to that, or was that needed as an addition?

Comment: Just the first 2 lines in the else statement